# Solve the equation $(-3A-4I)(kB+tI)=I$ for $k,t\in \mathbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As part of another problem I'm trying to solve, I'm struggling to solve the following equation for $k$ and $t$:

$$\overbrace{(-3A-4I)}^{B} \times \overbrace{(kB+tI)}^{B^{-1}}=I \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (*)$$

The reason I'm trying to solve this equation is to find $k,t\in \mathbb R$ such that $B^{-1}=kB+tI$.

It is worth to mention two things:

$(1)$ $A$ is a reflection matrix (i.e. $A^2=I$).

$(2)$ $B=(-3A-4I)$ and that's how I found the equation above $(*)$, I multiplied $B$ by $B^{-1}=(kB+tI)$.

Here is what I have so far:

$$(-3A-4I)(kB+tI)=I \implies \\
(-3A-4I)(k(-3A-4I)+tI)=I \implies\\ 
k((-3A-4I)(-3A-4I)) -3tA-4k(-3A-4I)-4tI = I \implies\\
k(9\overbrace{A^2}^{1}+12A+12A+16I) - 3tA +12kA+16kI-4tI=I \implies\\
24kA+16kI-3tA+12kA+16kI-4tI=I \implies\\ 
36kA-3tA+32kI-4tI=I$$

How can I continue from here to find $k$ and $t$ ? It seems like I have only one equation and two unknowns. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, your attempt is "tl;dr" to me. Anyway, we have

\begin{align}
B&=-3A-4I,\\
B^2&=9A^2+24A+16I,\\
&=24A+25I\quad (\because A^2=I)\\
&=8(3A+4I)-7I\\
&=-8B-7I.
\end{align}
Rearrange terms to get $B\left[-\frac17(B+8I)\right]=I$.

Comment: Oh so simple ! Thank you very very much. BTW, what "tl;dr" means?

Comment: Aha I found out in google. Again thank you very much. Anyway multiplying $B$ by $B^{-1}$ is what I was trying to do above but to no avail.